# Converting consuming tree into non consuming tree

Tags: rust

I have created the following tree with a consuming depth first traversal.

[Playpen](http://is.gd/0jZFDl)

```
struct TreeNode {
    value: i32,
    left: Option<Box<TreeNode>>,
    right: Option<Box<TreeNode>>,
}

fn main() {
    let root = build_tree();
    root.depth_first_pre();
}

fn build_tree() -> TreeNode {
    let root = TreeNode { value: 2,
        left: Some(Box::new(TreeNode { value: 7,
                            left: Some(Box::new(TreeNode { value: 2, left: None, right: None })),
                            right: Some(Box::new(TreeNode { value: 6,
                                                left: Some(Box::new(TreeNode { value: 5, left: None, right: None })),
                                                right: Some(Box::new(TreeNode { value: 11, left: None, right: None })) })) })),
        right: Some(Box::new(TreeNode { value: 5,
                            left: None,
                            right: Some(Box::new(TreeNode { value: 9,
                                                left: Some(Box::new(TreeNode { value: 4, left: None, right: None })),
                                                right: None })) }))};
    return root;
}

impl TreeNode {
    fn depth_first_pre(self) {
        print!("{}, ", self.value);

        if self.left.is_some() {
            self.left.unwrap().depth_first_pre();
        }

        if self.right.is_some() {
            self.right.unwrap().depth_first_pre();
        }
    }
}
```

Unwrap takes the value out of the option which is ok in this case since each value is only accessed once.

The problem occurs if I try to call the function twice:

```
root.depth_first_pre();
root.depth_first_pre();
```

This leads to errors on the second call of the function:

```
<anon>:10:5: 10:9 error: use of moved value: `root` [E0382]
<anon>:10     root.depth_first_pre();
              ^~~~
<anon>:9:5: 9:9 note: `root` moved here because it has type `TreeNode`, which is non-copyable
<anon>:9     root.depth_first_pre();
             ^~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

My understanding is that it's been moved out by the first function call and de-allocated once it went out of scope in that function.

How do I get around that?

I have tried changing the function to take a reference to self (`&self`) and changing `.unwrap()` to `as_ref()` but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: You should remove the `build_tree` method to produce a [MCVE](/help/mcve). Just `let root = TreeNode {value: 0, left: None, right: None};` is enough, and all the rest is completely unimportant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works just fine with <s>the changes you suggested</s> **adding** `as_ref`, not replacing `unwrap` with `as_ref`:

```
fn depth_first_pre(&self) {
    print!("{}, ", self.value);

    if self.left.is_some() {
        self.left.as_ref().unwrap().depth_first_pre();
    }

    if self.right.is_some() {
        self.right.as_ref().unwrap().depth_first_pre();
    }
}
```

However, it'd be far more idiomatic to use an `if let`:

```
fn depth_first_pre(&self) {
    print!("{}, ", self.value);

    if let Some(ref left) = self.left {
       left.depth_first_pre();
    }

    if let Some(ref right) = self.right {
        right.depth_first_pre();
    }
}
```

Comment: He said "changing `.unwrap()` to `as_ref()`", not "adding `as_ref()` before `unwrap()`; you did the latter. :P

Comment: @FrancisGagné ah, I guess my brain just parsed it as "I used `as_ref`".